# target_blank property with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

```js
document.getElementById("mahacareer").onclick = function () {
 location.href = "http://www.mahacareermitra.in";
};
```

```html
<a href="" target="_blank" id="mahacareer">Access the portal</a>
```

hello i want to open above link in new tab when i click on it.we use target="_blank" attribute with a tag but i want to use that attribute with JavaScript.

Comment: Duplocate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-and-not-a-new-window-using-javascript

Comment: links are used to navigate to other page then why you are using javascript to navigate?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
window.open('http://www.mahacareermitra.in','_blank');
```

or

You can use **SetAttribute** function in java script.

```
<a href=""  id="mahacareer">Access the portal</a>
```

Try this

```
  document.getElementById("mahacareer").setAttribute("target", "_blank");
```